# Selenium wait for Ajax content to load - universal approach

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

Is there a universal approach for Selenium to wait till all ajax content has loaded? (not tied to a specific website - so it works for every ajax website)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to wait for Javascript and jQuery to finish loading. Execute Javascript to check if `jQuery.active` is `0` and `document.readyState` is `complete`, which means the JS and jQuery load is complete.

```
public boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // no jQuery present
          return true;
        }
      }
    };

    // wait for Javascript to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return document.readyState")
        .toString().equals("complete");
      }
    };

  return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Will this work with every website or only with the websites using jQuery?

Comment: Will work on any website, it handles presence and absence of Jquery and JS

Comment: Thanks - i'll give it a try now

Comment: Great. It seems to work - does this also work with angularjs? Also - i'm not 100 aware of document.readyState - does this include if a webpage loads content via ajax? (e.g. Pinterest?)

Comment: @FabianLurz Yes I have been using it on pages with angularJs, it works well. AJAX page load will also fall under jQuery/JS and hence it should handle it as well.

Comment: @FabianLurz remember to make a call to this method every time your action on the webpage could potentially trigger an AJAX call or JS/Jquery load. Sometimes, the load may be complete but the element you want to interact with may not be accessible, in that case you have to wait for the element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93383/discussion-between-lings-and-fabian-lurz).

Comment: This is great! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @LINGS What is a correct method to call this with waiting?

Comment: Quick question guys, I'm just starting with a Cucumber Java framework and still don't know where all parts go. I tried creating a "public bool waitForJSandJQueryToLoad" method under "src/test/java/pages/helpers", but IntelliJ IDE fails to recognising it saying => "class or interface expected". Do you know where or how I should integrate this with my framework?

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Collin described in his book "Mastering Selenium Webdriver", use JavascriptExecutor let you figure out whether a website using jQuery has finished making AJAX calls

```
public class AdditionalConditions {

  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryAJAXCallsHaveCompleted() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);");
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But what if a side doesn't use jQuery?

Comment: Well if you have other javascript library you would need to rely on it. In the same book he has example for AngularJS, otherwise I would agree with another answer you have to be domain specific, and use [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this simple do while to iterate until an AJAX is finished. 
It consistently works for me.

```
public void waitForAjax() throws InterruptedException{
    while (true)
    {
        Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        if (ajaxIsComplete){
            info("Ajax Call completed. ");
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(150);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a universal approach out of the box. I typically make a method that does a `.waituntilrowcount(2)` or `waituntilvisible()` that polls an element.

Comment: Hm - dammn. Is there any other library that is capable of crawling ajax websites? 
Tried selenium, htmlunit and crawljax.

Problem htmlunit: Very sensitive against error and u can't turn it off.
Crawljax: Probably capable of crawling ajax but you can't get the html of a webpage - ouch
selenium: see question ;)