# Wait for gapi ajax calls in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-api-js-client

I need to wait all gapi calls in my automated tests.
In order to wait jquery ajax I execute script:

`browser.executeScript("return jQuery.active")`

And I can see number of active(unfinished) calls.

But in doesn't work for gapi calls.
Does anybody know to wait google api calls?

Comment: i think you can wait on the plain javascript `document.ReadyState` (as opposed to jQuery,Active) - saw something about it on this very forum a few days back

Comment: no, it doesn't work. `document.readyState` returns complete even if api calls in active state.

Comment: ok, back to the drawing board then :(

Comment: this was the answer i was thinking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348600/selenium-wait-for-ajax-content-to-load-universal-approach