# How do i make to wait for ajax which looks for jquery status active?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to wait until ajax gets successfully loads and jquery becomes active.
How could it make as a reusable function in among the methods?
I'm a newbie to selenium. Your help will make me understand the concept well.

```
List<WebElement> shipmentList = noOfShipment.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
int shipmentCount = shipmentList.size(); 
for (int row=1;row<shipmentCount;row=+1) { 
    try{ 
        WebElement onOfSkuWE= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fba-core-workflow-shi‌pment-summary-shipme‌​nt']/tr["+row+"]/td[‌​3]")); 
        String noOfSku = onOfSkuWE.getText(); 
        int noOfSkuValue = Integer.parseInt(noOfSku); 
        if(mskuType.equalsIgnoreCase("single")) { 
            if(noOfSku.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) { 
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//button["+row+"][@name='‌​Work on shipment']")).click(); 
                break; 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348600/selenium-wait-for-ajax-content-to-load-universal-approach

Comment: List<WebElement> shipmentList = noOfShipment.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  int shipmentCount = shipmentList.size();
  for (int row=1;row<shipmentCount;row=+1)
  {
   try{
WebElement onOfSkuWE= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fba-core-workflow-shipment-summary-shipment']/tr["+row+"]/td[3]"));
String noOfSku = onOfSkuWE.getText();
int noOfSkuValue = Integer.parseInt(noOfSku);
if(mskuType.equalsIgnoreCase("single"))
{
   if(noOfSku.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
   {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//button["+row+"][@name='Work on shipment']")).click();
    break;
   }
   }

Comment: don't add your code in a comment - edit the question instead, and make use of the code markup tool ... you should review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Code from Comment